# Fullscreen works in Chrome but not in Firefox in XMonad

Tags: firefox, xmonad, fullscreen

I have searched for people in similar situations, but mostly found out about people who could not make Chrome go fullscreen, but for whom Firefox would.

In my case, I can only get fullscreen to work in Chrome, and not in Firefox. What I mean is that when I press `F11`, Chrome covers correctly xmobar above, but Firefox not. Firefox enters its fullscreen mode, hiding the tabs menu and title bar all of that, but it remains tiled and not covering xmobar, like so:

[image: Firefox in fullscreen mode]

My `xmonad.hs` is very long, but I have narrowed it down as much as I could to make this easier:

```
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)
import XMonad.Hooks.FloatNext (floatNextHook)
import XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn
import qualified XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops as EWMH
import System.IO
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Layout.ResizableTile

myManageHook = manageDocks <+>
               floatNextHook <+>
               (isFullscreen --> doFullFloat) <+>
               manageHook defaultConfig
myLayout = smartBorders . avoidStruts $ Full ||| tiled
  where tiled = ResizableTall 1 (3 / 100) (2 / 3) [ 2 / 3]


main = do
  xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar"
  xmonad $
    EWMH.ewmh defaultConfig {
        manageHook = myManageHook <+> manageSpawn
      , handleEventHook = handleEventHook defaultConfig <+> EWMH.fullscreenEventHook
      , logHook = dynamicLogWithPP $ xmobarPP { ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc }
      , layoutHook         = myLayout
  }
```

The screenshot above was taken with this `xmonad.hs`.

I also can get [Zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) to go fullscreen, but not VLC nor Spacemacs.

Comment: for me fullscreen works perfectly  with : https://github.com/mimi1vx/dotfiles/blob/master/home/.xmonad/xmonad.hs

Comment: The workaround here -- setting the `full-screen-api.ignore-widgets` variable -- solved it for me: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1189622